# How to sync data between master and slave node in distributed systems

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, distributed-system

Can I get the clarification for the below question?

Given that 2 nodes one is R/W and another was a backup node, the backup node can have out of sync data, I have give few APIs like load, extract metadata, delete, update.
Can any tell me that what is algorithm can be used that the end of the algorithm both nodes have the same data

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways you can do this.

1. Every write to the R/W node you write to the backup node before returning.

   - Pros

     - Low complexity
     - Good if your application issues way more writes than reads.
     - Consistent backup
   - Cons

     - Slow writes
2. With every write to the to the R/W node, asynchronously write to the backup  node (you can return the write to the R/W node before the writing to the backup completes).

   - Pros

     - Faster writes
   - Cons

     - Data on backup may be out of sync for a few miliseconds/seconds.

It is normally okay for your backup to have out of sync data for a few seconds. Depending on your application requirements, it won't be a big deal if you miss the last few milliseconds of data. If strong consistency between the backup and your R/W node is absolutely necessary then go for option 1.